# Plot all pandas dataframe columns separately

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have a pandas dataframe who just has numeric columns, and I am trying to create a separate histogram for all the features

```
ind group people value value_50
 1      1    5    100    1
 1      2    2    90     1
 2      1    10   80     1
 2      2    20   40     0
 3      1    7    10     0
 3      2    23   30     0
```

but in my real life data there are 50+ columns, how can I create a separate plot for all of them

I have tried

```
df.plot.hist( subplots = True, grid = True)
```

It gave me an overlapping unclear plot.

how can I arrange them using pandas subplots = True. Below example can help me to get graphs in (2,2) grid for four columns. But its a long method for all 50 columns

```
fig, [(ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)]  = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize = (20,10))
```

Comment: you want 50+ histograms in 4 subplots?

Comment: Did you use tight layout?

Comment: @goyo not 4 subplots that was just an example

Comment: So it was an example of what you don't want. But what's what you want? How should the figure look like?

Comment: @goyo histogram graph for all the columns in a data frame, simple! In the above example, its 5 columns, in my real example it's 50. Can you write something generic? I am sure it can be done

Comment: It looks like you just need a bigger figure, but you already know how to do that so what is missing?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Pandas `subplots=True` will arange the axes in a single column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(7,20))

df.plot(subplots=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, `tight_layout` isn't applied, because the figure is too small to arange the axes nicely. One can use a bigger figure (`figsize=(...)`) though.

In order to have the axes on a grid, one can use the `layout` parameter, e.g.

```
df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(4,5))
```

[image]

The same can be achieved if creating the axes via `plt.subplots()`

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=5)
df.plot(subplots=True, ax=axes)
```

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest Could you figure out how to handle X and Y axis scale in each plot? ![Here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141666/how-to-change-the-color-of-individual-histograms-in-dataframe-hist-or-datafram)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to plot them separately (which is why I ended up here), you can use

```
for i in df.columns:
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(df[i])
```

Answer (score 11):

An alternative for this task can be using the "hist" method with hyperparameter "layout". Example using part of the code provided by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas  as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(7,20))

df.hist(layout=(5,4), figsize=(15,10))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) I would suggest using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). With a custom function, in this example `plot()`, you can print and save each figure seperately.

```
def plot(col):
 
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(col)
    plt.show()

df.apply(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

While not asked for in the question I thought I'd add that using the `x` parameter to plot would allow you to specify a column for the x axis data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(7,20),columns=list('abcdefghijklmnopqrst'))
df.plot(x='a',subplots=True, layout=(4,5))    

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

---

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html