# plot all columns of a pandas dataframe with matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have a dataframe with a datetime-index and 65 columns.
And I want to plot all these colums among themselves, 
not in a grid or in one figure.

```
df= test[['one', 'two', 'three','four']]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24, 5))
df.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

The example is all in one plot and not all among themselves.

Comment: What does "among themselves" mean? Can you explain that in your own words?

Comment: so that every chart has only one graph

Comment: Do you mean `df.plot(subplots=True)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567706/plot-all-pandas-dataframe-columns-separately

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the columns of the DataFrame and create a new figure for each column. This will plot them all at once. If you want the next one to show up once the previous one is closed then put the call to `plt.show()` inside the for loop.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


df = pd.DataFrame({
        'one': [1, 3, 2, 5],
        'two': [9, 6, 4, 3],
        'three': [0, 1, 1, 0],
        'four': [-3, 2, -1, 0]})

for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[col].plot(fig=plt.figure(i))
    plt.title(col)

plt.show()
```