# How to change the color of individual histograms in DataFrame.hist() or DataFrame.plot.hist( subplots = True ) function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

How to change the color of individual histograms in DataFrame.hist() function ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

# plot style
mpl.style.use("ggplot")

# DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randint(1, 5, size = 20),
                   "B": np.random.randint(4, 12, size = 20),
                   "C": np.random.randint(3, 10, size = 20),
                   "D": np.random.randint(100, 105, size = 20)})
```

```py
df.hist(figsize = (8,6)
```

[image]

**Desired Output**

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols =2, figsize = (8, 6))
colors = ["#e24a33", "#348abd", "#988ed5", "#777777"] # whatever the colors may be but it should be different for each histogram.
for index, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax = axes.flatten()[index]
    ax.hist(df[column], color = colors[index], label = column)
    ax.legend(loc = "best")
plt.suptitle("Desired Histograms", size = 20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**DataFrame.plot.hist()** is affecting the number of bins in each histogram.

```py
# one line code for above , but only issues with X axis and Y axis limits, which is effecting number of bins in each histogram. 
df.plot.hist(subplots = True,  layout = (2,2), figsize = (8,6))
plt.suptitle("#Bins effected in each histogram", size = 20)
```

[image]

**Is it possible to get the desired histograms by using the inbuilt function ** `df.hist()` or `df.plot.hist(suplots = True)`?

Comment: The following code can be used as a workaround. 
`fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 6));df['A'].plot.hist(ax=axs[0][0],color=colors[0]);...df['B'].plot.hist();df['C'].plot.hist();df['D'].plot.hist()`

Comment: @r-beginners ok so there's no inbuilt syntax to implement it.  Got it

Comment: I can't say for sure that df.plot(subplot=True) can't handle it. So I suggested it as a workaround.